# Angular 6 Nested FormArray

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a form with an array of fields generating by clicking '+' using Angular Reactive Forms. However, when I try to use `[formControlName]="index"` in child component it doesn't work.

Firstly it was saying that `formControlName` should have a parent with `FormGroup` I passed it and added. Now it says `Cannot find control name with unspecified name attribute`. In the Angular docs it's said that one able to use FormArray with `[formControlName]` and index since there is no names.

This is what I have
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-runxfe

Comment: why you have in your form `novalidate` but you have validators?

Comment: You problem is you are having a form and you are specifying thos index as part of you form which they don't exist. You will have to add them here this.fb.group({...}) as a text add the number 1:'' as a property and it will work the first time you press the + sign...now you gotta figure out how to add all those indexes dynamically to your fb.group object

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your issues. You needed to pass the formGroupName here:

```
<app-site-form-feature 
       *ngFor="let feature of features.controls; let last = last; let index = index; let first = first" [formGroupName]="index"
        [last]="last" [index]="index" [first]="first"
         (addFeature)="addFeature()" (removeFeature)="removeFeature(index, first, last)">
</app-site-form-feature>
```

HTML of the child component will look like this:

```
<div class="row no-gutters form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control px-2 col-10">
  <span class="btn btn-outline-danger" (click)="removeFeature.emit(index, first, last)">-</span>
  <span class="btn btn-success" *ngIf="last" (click)="addFeature.emit($event,index)">+</span>
</div>
```

Take a look to this stacblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v8zkz2

You can also reference this guide:
https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/